# Data in dropdown as per user id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to show data in the dropdown list as per the user who is logged in the application.

Below is the code from MasterT.aspx.cs
MasterT.aspx.cx

```
protected void Sauser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string s = (String.Format("SELECT top 1 user_id, Name,UserName, Password, Mobile, Role_id FROM Users where UserName='{0}' and Password='{1}'", LoginT.Text, PassT.Text));

                if (r.GetTable(s).Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    string v = " you must first log in or register before accessing this page";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + v + "');</script>", false);

                }
                else
                {
                    Session["user_id"] = r.GetTable(s).Rows[0]["user_id"]; **<----- I want to have this user_id.**

                    //  Response.Redirect("MasterDataEntry.aspx");
                    string v = " Welcome "+" "+ r.GetTable(s).Rows[0]["Name"]; ;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('" + v + "');</script>", false);

                }
            }
```

Below is drop down code,there is a field user_id in the GovEntities table.This user_id field should match the user id which is coming from MasterT.aspx.cx

MasterData.aspx

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="dbGovEntities" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="20%"
                    ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Bold="True" Style="text-align: center;"
                    Font-Names="arial" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
          DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>

               <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataEntryConnectionString %>" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [GovEntities] where user_id='@user_id'">   **<----- HERE**             
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```